# An exercise from Sarason's complex function theory book

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic map from the half-plane $Rez>0$ into the open unit disc. Prove that $|f'(z)| \leq \frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{2Rez}$

I think that I must modify the proof of Pick's lemma somehow but I have no clue how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $z_0$ with $\operatorname{Re}\,z_0>0$ and we define $$
\phi(z)=\frac{z-z_0}{z+z_0},$$
which maps the right half-plane onto the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$. Let $\alpha =f(z_0)$ and also we define
$$
\varphi (z)=\frac{z-\alpha }{1-\bar{\alpha} z}
$$
for $z\in \mathbb{D}$.

Consider $g(z)=\varphi \circ f\circ \phi^{-1}(z)$, which maps $\mathbb{D}$ into $\mathbb{D}$ with $g(0)=0$. We can apply Schwarz's lemma to see that$$
|g^\prime (0)|=|\varphi ^\prime (\alpha )\cdot f^\prime(z_0)\cdot (\phi^{-1})^\prime (0)|\le 1.$$
This shows that $$
|f^\prime (z_0)|\le \frac{1-|\alpha |^2}{2\operatorname{Re} z_0}.$$